# Weird DateTime bug?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird issue with datetimes in my database and PHP code.
`Carbon::now()` currently returns `2018-03-08 01:33:47` which is correct, that is the time on my computer and in my country.

I put a record with the `expires_at` value at `2018-03-08 02:32:02` which is in 1 hour (or 59 minutes of you want to become technical).

It wasn't displayed in my query, the query that is supposed to select all records where expires_at is before the current time, so non expired records.

Althought, when  setting the datetime to `2018-03-09 01:32:28` it displays that it expires in 23 hours? If I post it anything older (say 14 hours after the current datetime) it will be shown as expired?

```
$keys = UserAccountKey::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->get();
```

Comment: I don't know Carbon, but the first thing I would check is to make sure that these records also have the right user ID.  Then, check the raw MySQL query being generated by your PHP code, and compare that to what you get from MySQL admin.

Comment: `Carbon::now()` why not `NOW()` ? is your databases time the same as your servers time?

Comment: Yes, database time is the same as servers.

Answer (score 1):

The sql of your query is:

```
select * from `user_account_keys` where date(`expires_at`) >= '2018-03-08 01:33:47'
```

The `date('expires_at')` gets the date part of the `expires_at` field, ie '2018-03-08', obviously '2018-03-08' is less than '2018-03-08 01:33:47', so Your query did not get any result.

Just use `where('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now())` instead.

See this demo https://implode.io/vTWTWP